# SignalR 2 bind to custom userid from claims

Tags: c#, authentication, signalr, asp.net-mvc-5, claims

According to some posts i decided to try out the binding of the users by custom user id, no the `IPrincipal.Identity.Name`.

So I've implemented:

```
public class CustomUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
        string id = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == UserInfoIdClaimType)
                                   .Select(c => c.Value).Single();
        return id;
    }
}
```

But when this method is called, there are no claims in the identity ...

So i can't retrieve on this moment the claims from there?

Or maybe i should do it differently?

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that SignalR hubs kind of sit outside the regular ASP.Net environment. Some things aren't availble ( like session). I wonder if User/Identity is also one of them...

Comment: i've investigated the request and it seems it has like cookies and session id in it ...

Answer (score 0):

Solved issue, it seems that i haven't registered OWIN auth correctly when i did it in web config, it worked!

Comment: You should be using IRequest.User not Thread.CurrentPrincipal